# Android CursorAdapter BindView + multiple databases

Tags: android, cursor

I'm new to android and it's been a bumpy road so far trying to learn things to make a simple test project happen!

Here is my issue:

I have two simple tables that I need to use to populate a simple layout (custom list_item for listview).

The bindView function:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
```

takes only one Cursor but I need two in my case to fully populate my list_item. 
I was reading on ASyncTask() which sounds very useful but I don't believe that helps me in this case.
So my question is: How can I use the bindView() function with two Cursors?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should use a query to the database using a JOIN statement. This will "join" the values from one table to the other returning one cursor with the combined data. That is standard SQL stuff, just Google for "sqlite join"

Comment: I meant tables in a single database, not multiple databases, sorry I fixed it in the post already

Comment: I think JOIN statement may be what I need!! I will google it to learn about it more Thanks!

Comment: so use "sqlite join" as @Budius says and simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter` - no need for any `bindView` and such

Comment: @Am yep. They're kind of annoying, but are pretty powerful tools. My suggestion is to also find a SQLite DB that you can run on your computer (I've used this before http://sqlitebrowser.org/) so it's easy to test and fine tune the query you want to use on the PC before writing it in code.

Comment: great suggestions all of you guys! Thanks so much for your help!